# Network interfaces status tracking on FreeBSD

Tags: c, freebsd, systems-programming

I'm porting some software to FreeBSD 12 (it's never been run on FreeBSD). The software needs to track the system network interfaces and react immediately on status changes. It's assumed to run with root privileges. In FreeBSD 7 there was combination of `kevent` and EVFILT_NETDEV but this flag has been removed from FreeBSD 8 and later with no clear replacement.

I know there is a way to retrieve the interfaces using `getifaddrs` but no idea how to proceed and set handlers on `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` devices tracking the up/down events.

[`devd`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devd&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.2-stable&arch=default&format=html) looks promising given that it can catch the respective `IFNET` events, alas it's prohibited to adjust devd.conf on the target system, therefore I need to implement similar mechanism in my sfw. I have not much time to inspect the source code of devd even though I've tried and it made it even more cryptic.

Could anybody show me the right direction to go? Maybe some of the libdev* system-wide libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ask on the mailing lists or irc where the devs hang out?

Comment: @Rob No, I assume the mailing lists are for more important questions (like bugs), which trigger too many people.

Comment: That would be an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the respective library which uses devd's multiplexing pipe. It's called [`libdevdctl`](http://sources.freebsd.org/releng/12.2/lib/libdevdctl/) and its source code resides in `/usr/src/lib/libdevdctl`, written in C++, has no extra dependencies. Combination of `DevdCtl::Event::NOTIFY` and `DevdCtl::Consumer` was enough. For some reason the shared library in `/usr/lib` is called `libprivatedevdctl.so` and according to nm output exposes the needed interface. I reckon it's just an internal library so it's easier to grab the source and use as is in your software.

Also, it has a severe drawback, it `poll`s the socket with zero timeout in `DevdCtl::Consumer::EventsPending` which drastically increases CPU usage.